# search results and facet results do not match

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, facet

I'm doing `phrase_prefix` search for 'engineer' and I get 36 count for term 'Engineering' in 'skills' field facet. Next I apply a `term filter` on that facet field for 'Engineering' and in the new filtered results now the count for 'Engineering' in the facet is 42.

The filtered query returns 42 results, and each does match the facet, that is, they all contain 'Engineering' as a skill.

So I would expect the non-filtered query to have a 42 count for the 'Engineering' term in 'skills' facet, but as I mentioned above it's just 36.

Here's mapping and query
https://gist.github.com/santiago/a249418e5bf7531ead85

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

PD. I'm using 0.90.5

Comment: Try this gist: https://gist.github.com/eire1130/44d18734503267c835b9 run it twice, once with the filter bit and once without.

Comment: Same result. Without filter I see 36 counts for Engineering, while adding the filter shows 42.

Comment: Here's something to illustrate better the situation:
https://gist.github.com/santiago/ee65c9da0c6a5270dee0

The query returns 6 results, look that for each of these 6 exist skills for 'Microsoft Word', 'Microsoft Office' and 'English'. But look at the counts for these terms in the facets. 

'Microsoft Word' (5), 'Microsoft Office' (5) and 'English' (3)

Comment: what happens if you up the size=50 to something much larger like size=500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 0.90.5, you can get the results you expect by increasing the size of the facet list:

```
  "facets": {
    "skills": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "skills",
        "size": 50
      }
    },
```

The reason you get an inaccurate result, and why increasing the size helps is explained in the [Elasticsearch docs on term facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html):

> The size parameter defines how many top terms should be returned out
>   of the overall terms list. By default, the node coordinating the
>   search process will ask each shard to provide its own top size terms
>   and once all shards respond, it will reduces the results to the final
>   list that will then be sent back to the client. This means that if the
>   number of unique terms is greater than size, the returned list is
>   slightly off and not accurate (it could be that the term counts are
>   slightly off and it could even be that a term that should have been in
>   the top size entries was not returned).

In 0.9.6+, you can add a `shard_size` parameter to the facet, which tell it how many terms to request from each shard, before combining the results into one list.